# Configuring dovecot and postfix ssl setting by jks file

Tags: postfix, java, dovecot, keytool

I have CA JKS (Java Keystore) file which the CA bundle was added to it completely and we don't have any problem with java stuffs.

Now how may I export/manipulate, keys and required stuffs for setting up the dovecot and postfix ssl settings (with ca) from this JKS file? In CA manage section, I would have pem(for all my certificate, ca and root), crt and p7b files, but still don't know how to config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Postfix and Dovecot use Certificate-Key pair that has same format with Apache Certificate-Key pair. Because of that, you can <s>steal</s> use solution from this thread: [Converting a Java Keystore into PEM Format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656559/3604386).

Convert it pkcs12 format

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks \
       -destkeystore foo.p12 \
       -srcstoretype jks \
       -deststoretype pkcs12
```

To extract the certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out servercert.pem
```

To extract the private key:

```
umask 0077
openssl pkcs12 -in foo.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out serverkey.pem
umask 0022
```

The last step is configure postfix/dovecot to use that pair. There are tons of tutorial on the internet to configure it.

Main parameter for [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)

```
# Server side TLS
smtpd_use_tls = yes
# private key file
smtpd_tls_key_file = /path/to/serverkey.pem
# key you generated at cacert.org
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /path/to/servercert.pem
```

Main parameter for [dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration)

```
ssl = yes
# Preferred permissions: root:root 0444
ssl_cert = </path/to/servercert.pem
# Preferred permissions: root:root 0400
ssl_key = </path/to/serverkey.pem
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. pop3 is working now, no need to config `ssl_ca` for dovecot now? if yes how? only the CA intermediate cert file? or with root?

Comment: @TomIAm the [linked docs](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration#Client_certificate_verification.2BAC8-authentication) give detailed informations on the content of the file given by `ssl_ca`.